# Yii toggle database field

Tags: mysql, yii, sql-update, toggle

In my database table I have `status` column which is either 0 or 1.
I am making an action which have to toggle this field with minimum mysql requests. So in the action I would like to set

> $model->attributes['status'] = '1 - status';

and update the model.
Aperantly this does not work, but does anyone know an option for updating a db field using its current value without additional db requests and switching the field values.

The result query that will work is

> UPDATE 'users' AS 'User'  SET 'User'.'status' = 1 -'User'.'status'  WHERE 'User'.'id' = 1

Comment: Do you save $model? `$model->status = 1 - $model->status; $model->save();` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$model->status= 1 - $model->status;

$model->save();
```

Comment: My target is not to use `$model=$this->loadModel($id)` and what I have tried also is `User::model()->updateAll(array('status'=> '1 - status'),'id = '.$id );` - which does not work also

Answer (score 0):

we assume that you have the pk of the field you want to alter(since you don't want to create the model for it)

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
```

// build and execute the following SQL:

// UPDATE `tbl_user` SET `name`=:name WHERE id=:id

```
$command->update('tbl_user', array(
'name'=>'Tester',
```

), 'id=:id', array(':id'=>1));

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#building-data-manipulation-queries

Comment: this does not works also `$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->update('users', array(
    'status'=>'1-:status',
), 'id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));`

Comment: your code is wrong! are you trying to set the status to "1" or "1 - status"! can you share more? what won't work?? what error you get? did you set the id?

Comment: look the resulting query in the question, it works but unable to make it inside yii i would like to set status to `1 -'User'.'status'`